# Selecting distinct information from multiple similar/identical XML nodes

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file that looks something like the following - it constitutes an fixed format that I cannot change. The number of `<OrderLine>` values for each file is not fixed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DTD_ORDER>
   <OrderHead>
      <OrderReferences>12345</OrderReferences>
      <OrderRecipient>
         <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
            <Product>ProductA</Product>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Price>17.50</Price>
            <Discount>0.00</Discount>
            <LineGross>17.50</LineGross>
            <LineNet>14.58</LineNet>
            <LineTax>2.92</LineTax>
         </OrderLine>
         <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
            <Product>ProductB</Product>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Price>27.50</Price>
            <Discount>10.00</Discount>
            <LineGross>27.50</LineGross>
            <LineNet>22.92</LineNet>
            <LineTax>4.58</LineTax>
         </OrderLine>
      </OrderRecipient>
   </OrderHead>
</DTD_ORDER>
```

These XML files are currently imported into the PowerShell script in question via `[XML] (Get-Content $XMLFile)` as other operations are done on the file (deduplication, removing values etc).

The data for each `<OrderLine>` block needs to be appended to a CSV file that is created when the script first runs on the day in question. Information from elsewhere in the XML is currently being appended to a CSV file using the `-f` Format operator combined with `add-content`.

The end result should be a CSV like below....

```
OrderReferences, LineNumber, Product, DateCreated, Price, LineGross, LineNet, LineTax, OrderLineVoucherValue, Discount
12345, 1, ProductA, 20/02/2023, 17.50, 17.50, 14.58, 2.92, 0.00, 0.00
12345, 2, ProductB, 20/02/2023, 27.50, 27.50, 22.92, 2.92, 0.00, 0.00
```

I need to analyse the file in Powershell and query each `<OrderLine>` node and read all the tags inside it, extracting them into a CSV file.

I appreciate I could use Powershell's `SelectNodes("//OrderLine")` command, but as I understand it, that would return all of the tags (i.e. LineNumber, Product) into their own arrays, possibly out of order, when really I need to loop through the orderline tags and work on the sub tags. PowerShell probably has a *really* simple way of doing this, but I'm struggling to find the answer...

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml?view=powershell-7.3):

```sh
$dateCreated = '20/02/2023'

Select-Xml -Path input.xml -XPath '//OrderLine' | ForEach-Object Node | 
    Select-Object @(
        @{ n='OrderReferences'; e={ $_.ParentNode.ParentNode.OrderReferences }}
        'LineNumber'
        'Product'
        @{ n='DateCreated'; e={ $dateCreated }}
        'Quantity', 'Price', 'Discount', 'LineGross', 'LineNet', 'LineTax'
    ) | Export-Csv output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The `Select-Object` call takes an array that specifies which properties (columns) should appear in the output. The first one is a *[calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3)* that gets the `OrderReferences` value from the parent node, two levels up. There is another calculated property for the `DateCreated` column that references a variable.

The other properties are directly copied from the `OrderLine` element, so they can be simply specified by name. You can change the property order to your liking. You can either put each name on a separate line or separate them by `,`.

In case you already have the XML document in a variable, just remove the `-Path` argument and pipe the variable to `Select-Xml`:

```sh
$xml | Select-Xml -XPath '//OrderLine' …
```

To append to an existing CSV, just add the `-Append` argument to the `Export-Csv` call.

**Output:**

```
"OrderReferences","LineNumber","Product","Quantity","Price","Discount","LineGross","LineNet","LineTax"
"12345","1","ProductA","1","17.50","0.00","17.50","14.58","2.92"
"12345","2","ProductB","1","27.50","10.00","27.50","22.92","4.58"
```

Comment: Is it possible to inject the OrderReferences value into this output CSV output, as per the revised example?

Comment: @Optimaximal Done. I don't know where you get the `DateCreated` from though.

Comment: This will just be the XML file creation timestamp.

Comment: @Optimaximal I've added an example for `DateCreated`. It works similarly to `OrderReferences` by using a calculated property.

Comment: Thanks Zett42, you get BA because it was the one I ended up tweaking and implementing.

Answer (score 1):

Using the PowerShell Xml dot notation and [Member-Access Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration), it is probably easier then you think:

```
$Xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DTD_ORDER>
   <OrderHead>
      <OrderReferences>12345</OrderReferences>
      <OrderRecipient>
         <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
            <Product>ProductA</Product>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Price>17.50</Price>
            <Discount>0.00</Discount>
            <LineGross>17.50</LineGross>
            <LineNet>14.58</LineNet>
            <LineTax>2.92</LineTax>
         </OrderLine>
         <OrderLine>
            <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
            <Product>ProductB</Product>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <Price>27.50</Price>
            <Discount>10.00</Discount>
            <LineGross>27.50</LineGross>
            <LineNet>22.92</LineNet>
            <LineTax>4.58</LineTax>
         </OrderLine>
      </OrderRecipient>
   </OrderHead>
</DTD_ORDER>
'@
```

```
$Xml.DTD_ORDER.OrderHead.OrderRecipient.OrderLine |ConvertTo-Csv # | or: ... |Export-Csv .\My.csv    "LineNumber","Product","Quantity","Price","Discount","LineGross","LineNet","LineTax"
"1","ProductA","1","17.50","0.00","17.50","14.58","2.92"
"2","ProductB","1","27.50","10.00","27.50","22.92","4.58"
```

If you want to your own customization or formatting, you can do things along with:

```
$Xml.DTD_ORDER.OrderHead.OrderRecipient.OrderLine |Foreach-Object { $_.Product }
ProductA
ProductB
```

Or use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (and pipe that to e.g. `Export-Csv`):

```
$Xml.DTD_ORDER.OrderHead.OrderRecipient.OrderLine |Select-Object LineNumber, Product

LineNumber Product
---------- -------
1          ProductA
2          ProductB
```

To include the common `OrderReference` value you might start from the grand parent and use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties):

```
$Xml.DTD_ORDER.OrderHead |ForEach-Object {
    $OrderReferences = $_.OrderReferences
    $_.OrderRecipient.OrderLine |Select-Object `
        @{ l='OrderReferences'; e={ $OrderReferences } },
        LineNumber,
        Product,
        DateCreated,
        Price,
        LineGross
} |ConvertTo-Csv

"OrderReferences","LineNumber","Product","DateCreated","Price","LineGross"
"12345","1","ProductA",,"17.50","17.50"
"12345","2","ProductB",,"27.50","27.50"
```

Comment: Ok, so assuming that XML was already brought into a variable called `$xml_dest` via `[XML] (Get-Content $XMLFile)`, how would you reference that? (it's already part of a `ForEach-Object` loop as this script is working through multiple XML files doing other tasks)

Also, is there an instruction to append the rows to an existing CSV?

Comment: I have added some more details to the answer although it is not clear where you are *exactly* looking for. To prevent that we are building a case from a long list of comments, I suggest that you update the question and include an [mcve] with the expected outcome and the actual outcome. See also: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have done as requested.

Comment: Thanks iRon - The other answer was closer to what I implemented but you helped in several areas.